# Excel VBA Concatenate Unique Values Lookup

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Good morning! I'm trying to create a VBA function and appreciate any help you can provide to get me on the right track. In short, for each value in Column A of Worksheet Exams, I need to concatenate all the unique values in Column B in Worksheet Findings in which Column A of Worksheet Exams = Column A of Worksheet Findings. I'm struggling with where to start, and can't seem to find any good guidance. In advance, thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Started with this to get my bearings on the concat... I know the & ExamID portion is wrong, but I'm not sure what code I need there to Concatenate with the next instance of that RX721502:

```
Dim ExamID As Range
Dim strConcat As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    For Each ExamID In Range("A2:A10000")
        If InStr(ExamID.Value, "RX721502") > 0 Then
        Cells(i, 18).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) & ", " & ExamID
        End If
    Next ExamID
    Cells(2, 18) = Trim(Cells(2, 18))
i = i + 1
Loop
```

G

Comment: Yes, I know... I can't even get my damn concatenate to work. I've started with:

    Dim conOG As String
    Dim SourceExams As Worksheet
    Dim SourceFindings As Worksheet
    
    Set SourceExams = Sheets("Source-Exams")
    Set SourceFindings = Sheets("Source-Findings")
    
    For i = 1 To N + 3
        conOG = conOG & Cells(3, i)
    Next i

Comment: your narrative is about _"Worksheet States"_ and _"Worksheet Cities"_, while your _"code"_ shows `Sheets("Source-Exams")` and `Sheets("Source-Findings")`. You may want to update your code and clarify.

Comment: Adjusted... thank you...

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, it puts the `Concatenate` string of Cities in Worksheet **SourceExams**, Column 2.

```
Sub use_VLookup()


Dim conOG                               As String
Dim SourceExams                         As Worksheet
Dim SourceFindings                      As Worksheet
Dim lastrow, lastrow2                   As Long
Dim rowfound                            As Long
Dim Vlookup_result                      As Variant

Set SourceExams = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Source-Exams")
Set SourceFindings = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Source-Findings")

lastrow = SourceExams.UsedRange.Rows.count
lastrow2 = SourceFindings.UsedRange.Rows.count

For i = 2 To lastrow
    j = 2
    While j <= lastrow2
        ' search Worksheet Cities workcheet for match on Column A, and return the value in column B
        Vlookup_result = Application.VLookup(SourceExams.Cells(i, 1), SourceFindings.Range(SourceFindings.Cells(j, 1), SourceFindings.Cells(lastrow2, 2)), 2, False)
        If IsError(Vlookup_result) Then
            ' do nothing , you can add erro handling, but I don't think it's necesary
        Else
            conOG = conOG & ", " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SourceExams.Cells(i, 1), SourceFindings.Range(SourceFindings.Cells(j, 1), SourceFindings.Cells(lastrow2, 2)), 2, False)
            rowfound = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SourceExams.Cells(i, 1), SourceFindings.Range(SourceFindings.Cells(j, 1), SourceFindings.Cells(lastrow2, 1)), 0)
        End If

        j = j + rowfound
        ' if first found go to row 3
        If j <= 2 Then j = 3
    Wend
    SourceExams.Cells(i, 2) = conOG
    conOG = ""
Next i

End Sub
```